How do I make these nested match statements easier to read?
Still coding that awesome Turn based RPG.
I'm currently coding the logic for firstly selecting the attack then selecting the enemy (Or enemies)

    if event.is_action_pressed("ui_accept") and isSelecting:
        match currentSelectionType:
            SelectionType.SELECTING_ATTACK:
                currentSelectionType = SelectionType.SELECTING_ENEMIES
                match parent.attackActions[index].targetType:
                    Action.Target.SINGLE_ENEMY: select_single_enemy()
                    Action.Target.ALL_ENEMIES: select_all_enemies()
            SelectionType.SELECTING_ENEMIES:
                parent.deciding_finished.emit()

But I experience a metaphorical stroke every time I try to read this block of code ! How can i rewrite to make it more readable ?

You could put each match of SelectionType into separate functions.

@Raildex with a code sample, that would be a good answer, I think.
